# Mysql group_concat() re-orders resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Consider mysql schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `translations` (
    group_id INT(11),
    lang VARCHAR(2),
    text VARCHAR(9),
    UNIQUE INDEX `group_id_lang` (`group_id`, `lang`)
)
```

It should be quite obvious what is going on here - i have many translations for one group_id.

Now if i'll run following query, to get all groups with preferred language 'EN', fallback to 'RU', and if neither of these translations exists, then fallback to any available language, everything works as a charm

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM translations
    ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, lang = 'RU' DESC
) translations
GROUP BY group_id

+----------+------+---------+
| group_id | lang |  text   |
+----------+------+---------+
|        1 | EN   | Estonia |
|        2 | EN   | England |
|        3 | RU   | Швеция  |
+----------+------+---------+
```

As you see i'll get 3 rows with last one fallen back to 'RU' because 'EN' wasn't present on that group. So far all good..

Now if i want also select all available languages as a column by adding `GROUP_CONCAT(lang) AS translations`, then things get a bit fuzzy:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(lang) AS available_translations
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM translations
    ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, lang = 'RU' DESC
) translations
GROUP BY group_id

+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
| group_id | lang |   text    | translations |
+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|        1 | ET   | Eesti     | ET,EN,RU     |
|        2 | ET   | Inglismaa | ET,EN,RU     |
|        3 | RU   | Швеция    | RU,ET        |
+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
```

Now mysql doesn't respect my `ORDER BY` clause, and groups in native order as there's no ordering at all.

**Why is `GROUP_CONCAT` causing this issue?**

- My best guess would be mysql is reordering the result for easier text grouping..

**How i can make it to work to have preferred languages and also a list available translations by row?**

Also, if you'd like to fiddle around then [here you go](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3bc6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of results is not guaranteed until the outer most query, so even though you have ordered the subquery, this is not the guaranteed order the records are read, and returned by the outer query. The main issue though, is that you are abusing the MySQL Group by extension that allows you to select columns that are not contained in the group by clause or an aggregate function.

To simplify your query you have:

```
SELECT  group_id, text
FROM    translations
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, lang = 'RU' DESC
```

Unless `text` is functionally dependant on `group_id` this breaks the sql standard, but nonetheless, MySQL allows it, however, as stated in the [MySQL documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

So even though you have an order by this does not apply until after one row per group has been selected, and this one row is non-determistic. All you are doing is ordering the final result set.

In order to work around this and get determinsitic results, you can concatenate all the texts together using `GROUP_CONCAT` and explicitly state your required order:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(text ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, lang = 'RU' DESC)
```

Then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract just the first term. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT  Group_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    GROUP_CONCAT(lang
                                ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, 
                                        lang = 'RU' DESC), 
                    ',', 1) AS lang,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    GROUP_CONCAT(text
                                ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, 
                                        lang = 'RU' DESC), 
                    ',', 1) AS Text,
        GROUP_CONCAT(lang ORDER BY lang = 'EN' DESC, 
                                    lang = 'RU' DESC) AS available_translations
FROM    translations
GROUP BY Group_id;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3bc6/3)**

Comment: Very good explanation, everyday you learn something new :) Also, does joining another table happen before grouping, right? So if i'd like to join the grouped results with another table, then i should use current query in a subquery?

Comment: Yes, joining happens before grouping. I would guess you would need a subquery based on what you have said, but to a certain extent it depends on what you are joining to.

Comment: Well, actually my structure is like this: `[articles](id, created, user_id)` and `[articles_lang](article_id, lang, title, content, other translatable fields)`
And i'd like create a list of all articles, no matter which translataions they have. So an editor could see as much possible in his/her language, but still be able to see all the rows.
But yeah, i can take it from here, this gave some explanation of GROUP BY, and reason to dig to mysql manual. Cheers!